# Deploying Multi-Cluster/Multi-Region Gateway AND have redundant stateful services with GKE Autopilot?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes, cluster, google-kubernetes-engine

I want two clusters to each be in a different region so I have basic region redundancy. Some of the services I want to run are stateful (which includes keeping track of user sessions). I am not looking to maintain state if a cluster fails. I am just wanting a cluster B that I can direct the remaining traffic to if cluster A goes down. I see there are many ways to go about this. I looked at examples in the following links:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/migrate-gke-multi-cluster#migrate_to_multi-cl...
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-multi-cluster-gateways
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-multi-cluster-gateways#deploy-gatew...

The picture in the first link falls short due to it looking like the stateful service is just deployed in a single cluster. I want that stateful service to be deployed in all the clusters and, ideally, if in the event of the cluster failing, I would want all services choosing the next available stateful backend and sticking with it.

The third example looks almost like the setup I’m looking for. It seems that I would only need to do ServiceExport on the user facing services. But I have the following questions:

1. Requests to the GATEWAY_IP:80 will result in a default page displaying the following message: fault filter abort
   But, the diagram below shows if the user went to store.example.com/* it would redirect to either path. Will store.example.com without trailing slash go to the fail state? Is the fail state only if the actual gateway IP is entered into browser?
2. If I just specify the path prefix to be / so that all traffic can go to either cluster and so I don’t have to rewrite any site logic that relies on the URL structure, will the gateway service/resource intelligently map user traffic to the correct cluster (by ip address or other) so that if a user’s browser crashes, tab refreshes, user pastes a direct link to a page in a new tab while logged in an existing tab, or just even basic request to request remain at the same cluster as the first request? If not how can I accomplish this?